# What domain specific language have you used that you feel should be standardized across all languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, domain-driven-design

DSLs improve code readability and expressiveness  and more importantly give a significant level of abstraction..

You can agree that regular expressions, once you have mastered them , text processing becomes easy in any programming language you will learn.
What domain specific language have you used that you feel should be standardized across all languages?

Comment: This question is better asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Oded: Is language design no longer programming-related? There goes the neighborhood.

Comment: Your example "standard" isn't standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematics

Answer (score 1):

A standard notation for lambda expressions would be nice.

Comment: i dont think that would meet the criteria of a domain specific language...are lambda expressions really an abstraction?

Comment: @mossplix: lambda expressions are about as abstract as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

I am particularly enamored with [Groovy's XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlParser) as a "good" language syntax for XML:

1. facilitates XPath-ish (i.e. GPath) statements
2. direct access to nodes and attributes using simple dot notation syntax as opposed to "getNode()" or "getAttribute()" API calls.